# Robocopy really slow across LAN

Tags: file-transfer, robocopy, xcopy

DISCLAIMER: I'm a programmer, not an admin!

I am setting up web apps in a new server cluster and copying files using xcopy or robocopy and UNC paths between servers on the same subnet is really slow.  SOmetimes it seems to sporadically speed up, other times it is taking 2+ seconds to copy 5K files.  On our old environment this was lightning fast.  The only difference I know of is that was Win2K3 and this is Win2K8.  Could OS have anything to do with it, or is this more likely a weird network issue causing this?

Comment: What robocopy options are you using?

Comment: Pretty much any options, but usually just /S - it's the actual copying that takes a while.  The weird thing is sometimes I'll run it (same options) and it copies with the speed I'd expect other times I can sit and watch the percentage complete slowly change for small text files, etc, that should be so fast I don't even see the progress changing.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding /MT and removing /Z. This worked like a charmm for me:)

Comment: This change took my network utilization from 5% to 50% for a million file copy of 500kb files.

Comment: Yes, /z really speeds it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the possibility that your new server cluster has a different virus-killer, which might be set up incorrectly.

Just a thought, but this can slow filetransfers sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Double check you don't have TCP Offload enabled as well.  That can impact file copy speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Is it slow in both directions?  Is it slow from all other machines to the new box(s)?

Make sure there isn't a speed/duplex mismatch between a NIC and switch, disable auto-detect if it's on.

Comment: So far it seems to be slow in all directions.  I'm going to share these comments with my network admin and see if he can find anything.  Thanks!